# No active remote repositories configured

Tags: freebsd, pkg-config

In FreeBSD 8.4, pkg install is not working giving error.

```
$ pkg install git 
pkg:No active remote repositories configured.
```

**pkg_add -r application_name** is working and installing from ports is also it works fine but for above problem, is there any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a link saying the remote repo in /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf does not exist!
So we have to create one.

```
$ vim /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf
FreeBSD: {
url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
mirror_type: "srv",
signature_type: "fingerprints",
fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
enabled: yes
}
```

Also need to create the certificate https://svn0.us-west.freebsd.org/base/head/share/keys/pkg/trusted/pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301 in **/usr/share/keys/pkg/trusted/**

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/share/keys/pkg/trusted
$ wget https://svn0.us-west.freebsd.org/base/head/share/keys/pkg/trusted/pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301 --no-check-certificate -O /usr/share/keys/pkg/trusted/pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301
```

Now, we can update pkg and see if we have a repo:

```
/usr/share/keys/pkg/trusted $ pkg update -f
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
Fetching meta.txz: 100%    968 B   1.0kB/s    00:01
Fetching packagesite.txz: 100%    5 MiB  98.8kB/s    00:56
Processing entries: 100%
FreeBSD repository update completed. 24610 packages processed.
```

Comment: The URL to create the certificate gives an error. 
```fetch: http://geocoding.io/images/2016/02/pkg.freebsd.org.2013102301: No address record```
What else can be done?

Comment: Sorry, but the link seems to be dead! I had the certificate file on my local at that time but the local database has been formatted now!